# beautifulsoup, how to get text ignoring elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

it is possible to filter out only the text from the following structure:

```
"""<font>
   <em>X</em>
   and
   <em>Y</em>
</font>"""
```

to obtain the following output:

```
output = "X and Y"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<font>
   <em>X</em>
   and
   <em>Y</em>
</font>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

out = soup.find("font").get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
X and Y
```